# Arcpad Message Box and Keyboard Button Issue

Tags: arcpad

I'm using ArcPad 8 along with ArcPad Studio to create a custom application for use on Windows Mobile 6 devices. There are data entry forms and on those forms are buttons that, when clicked, present the user some information in a message box. For a button's onclick event, I specify an event script (using JScript) such as:

```
Application.MessageBox("Some information for the user...");
```

That all works fine. However, when the user dismisses the message box, the button for toggling the input keyboard/transcriber/recognizer that is located in the lower right corner of the application window immediately disappears, which prevents the user from showing and hiding the keyboard as they attempt to enter data in other various controls on the form. Has anyone else ever had this problem and know of any solutions? Thanks!

Comment: I would suggest that this is a bug request you should just send to Esri if you haven't already.

Comment: I'm dealing with the same thing.  The only solution that I've found is that if you do not close the message box (by clicking "ok"), and just click somewhere else on the custom data entry form, you don't loose the keyboard. Still looking for a better solution though.  Anybody?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a verified bug in ArcPad.  I encountered this problem and several others back in ArcPad v8.1 and submitted this bug to ESRI on September 13, 2010.  ESRI assigned it the bug report number CQ00312491.  It was supposed to be fixed in ArcPad v10.0.2 but, to the best of my knowledge, it has not been fixed (the status is still listed as Open).  I don't think any of the other ArcPad bugs that I verified, reported, and were assigned bug numbers back in 2010 have been fixed either.  Provided you are using vbScript, as a workaround you can use the MsgBox statement [( MsgBox )](http://www.w3schools.com/VBScript/func_msgbox.asp).